# insert javascript into wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am currently working with a javascript function that I have inserted inline into a wordpress  post -- here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
document.getElementById('FBsharer').onclick = function () {
  var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=';
  url += encodeURIComponent(location.href);
  window.open(url, 'fbshare', 'width=640,height=320');
};
// ]]></script>
```

The code works fine while inserted inline into my post--

But when I try to call the javascript in from an external file located in my wp_includes folder-- it no longer works.

I know that the JS file i am calling in from WP_includes works-- because I have other scripts in that file which work fine.

I am pretty new to JS-- so I am sure that im just formatting something wrong- or missing something simple.

**Does anyone know how I can move this JS file from its current location (inline in my post) to my JS file that I am calling in from the wp_includes folder?**

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Never update anything in `wp_includ` folder. Better add you js in your theme folder & include it in your header file.

Answer (score 1):

You just create a file or folder inside your wp-content/thems folder and save your script file after link it by header.php file inside your theam. Never change wp-include folder and content.

**Normal link**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/emailpage.js"></script>
```

**Wordpress link**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/pathto/yourscript.js"></script>
```

For more references [follow this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript)